# No alignment in minipage figures

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, minipage, subfig, sidebyside

I am trying to insert pictures side by side. I used the minipage method after having no luck with the subfigure method. Here's my code,

```
\begin{figure}[h]  
     
\centering               
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.4\textwidth}  
\vspace{0pt}  
\includegraphics[scale=.5]{undamped_input_filter}
\caption{\small{Bode plots of \textcolor{red}{undamped filter},\textcolor{blue} 
 {converter input impedance}}}
\label{fig:bodefilteru}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{2cm}
\begin{minipage}[b]{.45\textwidth}
\centering
 \vspace{0pt}
\includegraphics[width=4cm, height=3cm]{undamped_input_filter_ckt}
\caption{\small{LC filter circuit}}
\label{fig:LCfilter}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

But the Output I get has no alignment of the images. I tried to use "scale" as well as the "width=, height=" commands, but I'm not doing something right. Can someone tell me what's wrong or tell me what to do in the subfigure method?

[image]

Comment: you used `[b]` so as your post shows they are aligned on the last line of the captions.

Comment: What happens if you replace `\hspace{2cm}` with `\hspace{\fill}`?

Comment: Consider accepting the provided answer sine it seems to have solved the problem according to your comment,

Answer (score 2):

Use `\begin{minipage}[t]`

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}[h]  
        \centering              
        \begin{minipage}[t]{.4\textwidth}
            \centering  
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{\small Bode plots of \textcolor{red}{undamped filter}, \textcolor{blue}{converter input impedance}}
            \label{fig:bodefilteru}
        \end{minipage}
    \hfill
        \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}  
            \centering      
            \includegraphics[width=4cm, height=3cm]{example-image-a}
            \caption{\small LC filter circuit}
            \label{fig:LCfilter}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

Using subfigures the captions will be different (of course)

Adding `\usepackage{subcaption}`

[image: c]

with this code

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
        \centering  
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{\small Bode plots of \textcolor{red}{undamped filter}, \textcolor{blue}{converter input impedance}}
        \label{fig:bodefilteru}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering      
        \includegraphics[width=4cm, height=3cm]{example-image-a}
        \caption{\small LC filter circuit}
        \label{fig:LCfilter}
    \end{subfigure} 
    \caption{\small Two filters}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried this way, but my figures were further misplaced, but I hadn't known about the placement thing here. I learnt it from your answer, so I got it to work with [c].